# VSCode 1.25 update breaks imports

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have `jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*", "src/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules", "coverage", "build", "reports"]
}
```

after upgrading to `VSCode 1.25` from `1.24.0`, IDE automatically updated all my files with updated imports.

Some of them are valid like

`import log from './Logger';`

was replaced with

`import log from 'common/services/Logger';` ,

although it does not make sense. But others are totally broken like

`import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';`

was replaced with

`import { createLogger } from '../../../../../../../../../Users/waszczpa/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/2.9/node_modules/@types/redux-logger';`

How this can be fixed? I need two things:

- do not automatically use absolute paths. `import log from './Logger';` makes more sense because I'm importing file from the same directory.
- fix broken `AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/2.9/node_modules/@types` stuff.

I guess, this has something to do jsconfig file.

Comment: have the same problem. I turned of auto import update with the following setting

`"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "prompt"`

Comment: Yeap, it works, thx. I already did the same. It's a pity